# Handling density / font size change on Android Nougat

Tags: android, fonts, size, display, android-7.0-nougat

I want to make my application compatible with Android Nougat and specifically with the density change and the font size change.

What I am doing in my tests is:

- Launch the application
- Put it in Multi-Window mode (top part of a Pixel C, portrait mode, on emulator)
- Put some filters on a list in my application
- Change the display size or the font size through the second half of my screen with the settings app

If I don't listen for configuration changes with the density value in the manifest, it recreates my activity (which is not good because I have some filters on and I lose them).
If I listen to them, the densityDpi value is the same in the newConfig value passed as a parameter than the one I get with getResources().getConfiguration().densityDpi.

My current line on the manifest is as below :

`android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation|keyboardHidden|density"`

I have tried something like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  // some code
  if(mOldConfiguration != null && newConfig.densityDpi!= mOldConfiguration.densityDpi){
  // Neither densityDpi nor fontScale works, they are always the same
  }

    if(mOldConfiguration != null && newConfig.fontScale != mOldConfiguration.fontScale){
    // I will later have a method which will recreate the activity with my filters saved
        recreate();
    }
    mOldConfiguration = newConfig;
}
```

I already listen to other configuration changes but can't figure out how to detect in this method that the change was a density / font size change.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can listen to density changes by add this line in the Manifest file:

   ```
   android:configChanges="density"
   ```

   In the activity, you can get the new configuration value when having a change:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       Log.e("TRUNGDH", newConfig.densityDpi + "<= densityDpi");
   }
   ```
2. With font size changes, you can add some code like this:

   ```
   android:configChanges="fontScale"
   ```

   ```
   @Override
   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
       Log.e("TRUNGDH", newConfig.fontScale + "<= fontScale");
   }
   ```